# how can I solve There was an error downloading metadata from the address error in WCF in VS 2008?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have an existing  project with a  silverlight3 app. First I created SALESservice.svc.This is working fine. Now I added another TARGETservice.svc to my project

and rebuilded my entire project but when I am trying to add the service reference in to the silverlight app I get the following error:

There was an error downloading metadata from the address.  Please verify that you have entered a valid address.

I didn't write any code in ISALESservice.svc AND ITARGETservice.svc . I have written in SALESservice.svc.cs  AND  TARGETservice.svc.cs files.Is this causing error?
But for SALESservice.svc it is working. I didn't add any code in web.config file.

Regards,
JN

Comment: - What webserver are you using ? Is it the Visual Studio's build in webserver (cassini) ? - Is your project set to always run on the same port ? - Are you adding a webservice reference to a service that's hosted via a web server or are you attempting to add an existing service from the solution ? Is your web (the asp.net) project your startup project ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problems. Let's assume he is using IIS for hosting his services. So, were to look first?

Answer (score 0):

try accesing the url of your service from your browser, I had the same problem in my case it was that I didn't have enough memory to use the service, I closed some programs and boya!! it worked like a charm. Hope it helps